# How to make the layout of fragment with height of the screen height except bottom navigation view?

Tags: android, xml

I faced with the following problem: I need to make a fragment, which height would be the same as height of the screen except bottom navigation view. Here's my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.main.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#111111"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_nav" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_nav_height"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I added `android:background="#111111"` to see, what is the real height of fragment. Probably I thought that `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_nav"` can help me, but unfortunately it didn't solve my problem. So, how can I deal with it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the layout_height of the FrameLayout to 0dp if you want the height to fit your constraints.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.main.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs_fragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#111111"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_nav"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_nav_height"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```